# Debugging frozen Gnu screen session?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

We've been using GNU screen on our jump box to have ssh sessions open to multiple hosts within our private network. One window per host.

Recently we've built a new environment and are experiencing frequent screen hangs. 
Most often when a lot of terminal output is being spooled to the screen (cat'ing a file for instance), screen becomes unresponsive. The terminal stops updating mid-command, and I can't switch to any other screen window.

I can log into the jump box again, and do a screen -dr , and it attaches like nothing was the matter.
The .screenrc we use is:

```
bindkey -k k2 screen
bindkey -k k3 prev
bindkey -k k4 next
bindkey -k k7 copy
bindkey -k k8 title
bindkey -k k9 windows
startup_message off
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%-w%{= BW}%50>%n %t%{-}%+w%<"
nonblock on
```

While a screen session is frozen like this, can you suggest what I should be looking at to work out what the cause is because I'm fairly stumped?

This is under debian wheezy, screen=4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-7, and these are EC2 instances in case that's relevant.

Comment: If you cat a file, the terminal may end up interpreting a sequence. You can try a couple of things: check if you can issue `reset` and also try to toggle XON/XOFF.

Comment: OK will try that next time. 

If it happens because of a control sequence in a file, then it should always happen when cat'ing that file right?

Should add it's not always cat'ing a file, sometimes just a command that generates a lot of output. Also, sometimes the sessions appears to recover after hanging for 20+ seconds.

Comment: This could be an MTU problem in the underlying network. That is, there is a packet larger than the network MTU, and it gets dropped at some point in the network, therefore freezing the connection.

Comment: `bindkey`? You're using `zsh`?  What happens if you change shells (`bash`)?

Answer (score 4):

On occasion, the xterm you're using gets a `Ctrl-S` from whatever output is being parsed.
This causes the session to "lock" in place (like a "pause"), and you can hit `Ctrl-Q` to resume.
There have [been](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2000/06/msg00767.html) [several](http://www.thecorneroffice.org/blog/plink/2005/03/050312-0153.html) [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182216/xterm-randomly-hangs-while-scrolling-in-vim-inside-screen) where this happens.

**History:** `Ctrl-S` sends a "Software Flow Control Off (XOFF)" to the remote host, `Ctrl-Q` sends the XON.

**SSH Tip:** If the above doesn't work; Next time the SSH session hangs on you, type `~.` (that's "Tilde" and "dot".  That should axe the hung SSH session and get you back to screen.